# how to not push node_modules to git

Tags: git, visual-studio

how to not push node_modules to git

i don't want to push node modules to git from VS code .

```
git add .
git commit -m "Add .gitignore to exclude node_modules"
git push origin <branch-name>
```

the node_modules directory should be excluded from your Git repository, and i won't push it when using VS Code to commit and push changes

Answer (score 2):

If node_modules is already committed to the repo, delete it and commit the deletion to the repo.
Then add a .gitignore file at the root of the repo (where I presume your node_modules is present). This file is used to specify which files need to be excluded from git tracking.
Add node_modules to the .gitignore file.

```
# dependencies
/node_modules
```

Save .gitignore and commit it to the repo.
One other common file/files that usually goes into .gitignore is the environment variables file (.env/environment.ts).
Refer to the documentation for more details:
[Git - gitignore Documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore#:%7E:text=The%20purpose%20of%20gitignore%20files,tracked%20by%20Git%20remain%20untracked.)